# How to recalculate shipping costs in Magento one page checkout

Tags: checkout, shipping

I have the following requirement for a shipping module in Magento:
on the shipping method step on one page checkout in Magento, the user should be able to add additional options to a particular method (are there any fragile items, pick up from warehouse, add insurance etc.).  Based on that, I have to recalculate shipping costs.  In essence, I need to get the submitted options, make an API call, and represent the new costs to the user.  Currently I have overriden `Checkout_OnepageController` successfully.
How can I repeat that step?

Answer (score 2):

You can recalculate totals by using `collectTotals()` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php` by getting the quote. For example:

```
$this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Marceli, but i need to add to the costs to the shipping methods alone.Basically i need to add some costs in collectRates method in the custom carrier object.To do that i will use the parameters submitted in the $_POST array and then redisplay the new values to the customer, but in order to do that i need to submit co-shipping-method-form first (via additional button).

Comment: Check collectShippingRates() method in the same file maybe this will help you.

Comment: Yes, i am just playing with this method.It seems that there is no other way to achieve what i want.Thank again Marceli!